# Linq to objects List in list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a list of movies

```
List<Movie> MovieList
```

and I have a list of selected categories

```
List<string> SelCat
```

And say I want to select from the movie list where it matches 2 categories, like the SQL statement below:

`SELECT * FROM MovieList WHERE MovieList.Category = 'Action' AND MovieList.Category = 'Drama'`

I can get kinda close with linq like so:

`var q = (from b in MovieList where b.Categories.Any(p=> SelCat.Contains(p)) select b);`

But it acts like an OR query, not an AND. I want it to select all movies that have a category of action and drama.

BTW: **Movie.Categories is a List of string**. AND **Movie.Categories must contain items in the SelCat**.

How do I achieve this with Linq to Objects?

Comment: MovieList.Category = 'Action' AND MovieList.Category = 'Drama', don't you mean MovieList.Category = 'Action' OR MovieList.Category = 'Drama'

Comment: No, MovieList.Categories is a List<string>

Comment: You want to find all films that are ACTION and DRAMA? So a film that only has DRAMA in its categories is not one you want?

Comment: Yes. All films that have action AND drama. or whatever is in the SelCat list of string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var q = from m in MovieList where SelCat.All(c => m.Categories.Contains(c))
```

Quite close to what you would say describing the problem in English:

Select movies where the movie categories contain all the categories in `SelCat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the movie to match *all* of the interesting categories (i.e. all of the categories in `SelCat` are present in `movie.Categories`), you can do:

```
MovieList.Where(movie => !SelCat.Except(movie.Categories).Any());
```

On the other hand, if you want the movie to match *atleast* 2 of the selected categories:

```
MovieList.Where(movie => SelCat.Intersect(movie.Categories).Count() >= 2);
```

Comment: Close, but I only get 132 records when I should have 183. Thanks for trying!

Comment: +1 the OP is giving a bad example. "Action" and "Drama" made others hard code, but essentially they are elements in the `SelCat`.

Comment: @Rick Ratayczak: If you can describe *why* this isn't what you want, that would be helpful.

Comment: SelCat contains any number of strings in a List<string>. Movie.Categories must contain all of the SelCat items. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @Rick Ratayczak: That's *exactly* what my first query does.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var SelectedCategories = List<string>();//list of selected categories

from movie in MovieList
join selCat in Categories.Where(SelectedCategories.Contains(selCat.Category)
on movie.category equals selCat.category
select movie
```

Answer (score 0):

just do an intersect followed by except.
it works, im sorry i had to write it in vb.

```
Dim categories As New List(Of String)
Dim selected As New List(Of String)

        categories.Add("ali")
        categories.Add("ali2")
        categories.Add("ali3")
        categories.Add("ali4")

        selected.Add("ali2")
        selected.Add("ali4")


        Dim common = categories.Intersect(selected)

        If common.Except(selected).Count = 0 Then
            'true
        Else
            'false
        End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not the right answer. I don't know if it will be action or drama or comedy, but the Movie.Categories must contain items in the SelCat.

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted:

```
var moviesInSelCat = MovieList.Where(m => SelCat.All(sc => m.Category.Any(c => c == sc)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from movie in movieList
             where selCat.All(selectedCategory => movie.Categories.Contains(selectedCategory))
             select movie;
```

remember the difference between `.All()` and `.Any()`

Comment: This will select movies whose categories are a subset of the selected categories. The OP wants to achieve the opposite effect.

Comment: Thank you, but I get 0 records from that query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var matches = MovieList.Where(m => SelCat.Except(
    m.Categories.Intersect(SelCat)).Count() == 0);
```

Comment: This is close also, but only returns 132 records when I know there is 183. Thank you!